# Function from a quotient space onto a quotient space

Tags: general-topology

consider $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ two equivalence relations over $X$ and $Y$, respectively. let a continous function $f$ such that $xR_{1}y$ implies $f(x)R_{2}f(y)$, i want to show that the induced relation $\hat{f}:X/R_{1}\rightarrow Y/R_{2}$, given by $\hat{f}([x])=[f(x)]$ is well defined and is continous.

1.continuity:

I consider the canonical projection map $\pi: Y \rightarrow Y/R_{2}$ given by $\pi:x \mapsto [x]$. Consider $U^{\text{open}}\subseteq Y/R_{2}$, then $(\pi^{-1}(U))^{\text{open}}\subseteq Y$, as $f$ is continous note that

$$(f^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(U)))^{\text{open}}\subseteq X$$

From this I could say something like $(f^{-1}(\pi^{-1}(U)))=(\pi \circ f)^{-1}(U)$

and that composition function should be continuous, but I am not sure about it; how can I conclude with this?

On the other hand, and something that seems a little less relevant, how do I guarantee that this application is well defined? any suggestions? any help is welcome!

Comment: What does it mean (to you) for $\hat{f}$ to be *well-defined*? Do you know about the universal property of the quotient topology?

Comment: @ronno I don't see it, is it obvious that it is well defined?

Comment: It shouldn't be obvious if you don't know what it means for a function to be well-defined.